# i want to echo text if this for each loop is not empty

Tags: php, html, foreach

below is my for each loop. i want to check if the loop is not empty, and then echo "this loop is not empty" else echo"this list is empty"; what is the syntax for this?

```
foreach ($wholikes as $key => $list2){
echo "is in the list".$list2['userid'];
}
```

Comment: Which kind of variable-type is `$wholikes` of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(empty($wholikes)){
    echo "This list is empty";
}else{
    foreach ($wholikes as $key => $list2){
        echo "is in the list".$list2['userid'];
    } 
}
```

Comment: From the info the OP gave, thats exactly what I was about to post :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !$wholikes) echo "Empty";
```

That's literally all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

The two previous answers will work in that case, but in the more general case of a loop you'd want:

```
$notEmpty = 0;
foreach ($wholikes as $key => $list2){
    $notEmpty = 1;
    echo "is in the list".$list2['userid'];
} 
if(notEmpty) {
   echo "Not empty.";
} else {
    echo "Empty";
}
```